# "No Feature Points" and "Bad Params" and no luck with align_image_stack

Tags: image-alignment, auto-alignment

I want to align aseveral images that contain the progress of assembling an electronic circuit [sample images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XWXv.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJZE.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiUUe.jpg]

On Windows 10, I open them in Hugin (version 2019.2.0.b690aa0334b5), select "Align image stack" under settings, chose "positions (y, p, r)" under geometric optimization as well as the default "low dynamic range" under photometric optimization:

[image]

I then click on "Create control points" it gives me the error message "align_image_stack.exe failed with error code: 1" as you can see here:

[image]

Okay, so I tried the same in command line and tried a command line call via `align_image_stack -a al -t 3 -c 20 img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg`, but to no avail:

[image]

It tells me "No Feature Points" and "Bad Params." The debug.pto file has this content here: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IUF3V

What can I do?

Comment: It is possible that Hugin looks mostly along the borders of the image, and since your image has very wide margins, it cannot find anything intresting there. Try with a much tighter crop around the circuit board. Or IIRC you can set interest points yourself, in which case the 4 corners of the board would be good candidates.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any reference on how to set the interest points via command line?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use an image stack (this is meant for images with the same content but different exposures).
Instead just do a regular alignment, I just tried with your 3 example images (on a Mac), this works fine.

Comment: Will give this a try! I had given up hope on this altogether, and have been using Photoshop so far, for $9.99 a month, sigh. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot find this "regular alignment" option, could you tell me how to activate it?

Comment: Leave the default setting (Hugin's CPFind) and do not use an image stack. Just click on 'Create control points' (and then Optimize -> Geometric -> Calculate). If you find the alignment to be inaccurate, you may need to manually remove some.